# Spring security not able to autowire dependency

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to integrate Spring Security in my Spring MVC project. The version of spring that I am using is 4.2. 
I am encountering issue when autowiring dataSource bean, which I undersatand is because WebSecurityConfig class calling before WebConfig.

Following is my code for WebSecurityConfig -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSource")
DataSource dataSource;




@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password from users where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username=?");


}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
      .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
}
}
```

And here is WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xyz.abc.*"})

public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
  registry.jsp().prefix("/WEB-INF/views/").suffix(".jsp");
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
DataSource dataSource() {
   DataSource dataSource = null;
   JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
   try {
       dataSource = jndi.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/GenericDataSource", 
 DataSource.class);
     } catch (NamingException e) {

     }
    return dataSource;
}


@Bean public DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping 
defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping(){
   DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping bean = new 
 DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping();
   bean.setUseDefaultSuffixPattern(false);
    return bean;
  }

   @Bean public AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter 
 defaultAnnotationMethodHandlerMapping(){
  AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter bean = new 
AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter();
   return bean;
}

   @Bean
  public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(52428800);
    return resolver;
}


@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

 registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").
 addResourceLocations("/static/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
 }

 }
```

StackTrace-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: javax.sql.DataSource com.abc.xyz.WebSecurityConfig.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=dataSource)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: javax.sql.DataSource com.abc.xyz.WebSecurityConfig.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=dataSource)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=dataSource)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
    ... 45 more
```

How to resolve this? Please help.
TIA

Comment: Your `dataSource` method implementation is wrong. I suspect you get an exception during the lookup, which you catch and swallow. Resulting in `null` being returned, aka no bean. Remove the try/catch and simply add a throws clause to the method. It will then probably blow-up with a JNDI error. Tip use the `JndiDataSourceLookup` instead of the `JndiTemplate`. Spring will figure out the order itself, so it isn't a problem of ordering. Also the `@EnableWebSecurity` is needed only once.

Comment: Also HOW are you loading these configurations? You either have a `web.xml` or `WebApplicationInitializer` loading the `ContextLoaderListener` and/or `DispatcherServlet`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's name conflict and you should change bean's name. something like *"myDataSourceBean"*

Another approach is to use `Primary` annotation instead of `Qualifier`